# Bluebird Promise Warning: .then only accepts functions but was passed

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

Using `"bluebird": "^3.4.6"` :

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

Promise.config({
    warnings: true,
    longStackTraces: true,
    cancellation: true,
    monitoring: true
});


function getPromise1(param1, param2) {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => { 
        console.log(param1, param2); 
        resolve();
    } );
}

function getPromise2(param1, param2) {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => { 
        console.log(param1, param2);
        resolve();
    } );
}


function mainFunc(param1, param2) {
    getPromise1(param1, param2)
        .then(getPromise2(param1, param2));
}

mainFunc("param1", "param2");
```

When I run it, I get :

```
$ node index.js
param1 param2
param1 param2
(node:95984) Warning: .then() only accepts functions but was passed: [object Object]
```

How can I modify this piece of code to do the same thing without the warning? Is this warning pertinent or is it just a heads-up for the developer?

**EDIT**: Yes. I understand the text of the warning, i.e. `.then` expects a function when it actually gets a `Promise` object from the `getPromise2` function. Nevertheless, **the promise gets called**. (helpful downvotes)

My predicament is **how to chain promises** in such a way that a **new Promise** will be called in the `then` function after the first promise executes.

Comment: You're calling `getPromise2` instead of passing it as a parameter to `then`. So you're passing its returned promise to `then`, not the function. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: When you call `.then(getPromise2(param1, param2));`, this code runs `getPromise2(param1, param2)` immediately and then passes the returned promise to `.then()`.  But you aren't supposed to pass a promise to `.then()`.  You're supposed to pass a function.  So, that's why the warning.  It isn't clear what you're trying to do since you don't describe that.

Comment: @jfriend00 I've edited the question to be more descriptive.

Comment: @JohnnyHK I've edited the question to better explain what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Notice that promises are never "called", they're value object. You can only call the function that creates the promise.

Comment: FYI, the downvotes were likely because you did not explain what you were trying to accomplish in your original question - what you wanted the desired result to be.  That's a critical point of any question here.  Not just describing the wrong output and the wrong code, but describing the desired output.  As soon as you clarified that, you got two answers fairly quickly.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for clearing that up for me and for your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `getPromise2()` call immediately creates the promise; it then is ignored being passed to `then` instead of a callback. To actually chain them, you'd need to use

```
function mainFunc(param1, param2) {
    return getPromise1(param1, param2).then(function(promise1result) {
        return getPromise2(param1, param2);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The key is that you have to pass a function to `.then()`.  You were executing your function immediately and passing the returned result from that function (which was a promise).  So, you can create your own anonymous wrapper function as in Bergi's answer or you can use `.bind()` as in:

```
function mainFunc(param1, param2) {
    return getPromise1(param1, param2).then(getPromise2.bind(null, param1, param2));
}
```

`.bind()` creates the wrapper function for you and allows you to specify the arguments you want preprended to the argument list when the function is actually called at a later time.